# KML vertical lines between polygons in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm adding a KML layer to a Google Map. The KML file is generated using Grads (version 2.1.a3) and then uploaded to our web server. [The layer appears on Google Maps, but vertical lines appear on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfJF3.png). These lines appear to join interior polygons to exterior ones.

I originally thought this was a Grads issue in which the program was having trouble rendering polygons with holes, however, I've checked the same layer on [Google Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGuVQ.png), and the lines are not present. To me this implies that the problem resides with either the way in which the KML file is interpreted in Google Maps or my own coding error.

The KML layer is loaded into Google Maps by:

```
var kmlUrl = 'http://www.urltokml.com/kmlfile.kml?'+Math.random();
var kmlOptions = {
    suppressInfoWindows: false,
    preserveViewport: false,
    map: map
};
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl,kmlOptions);
```

The KML file contains many different polygons, so a sample is shown below.

Does anyone know what can cause these lines to appear? Are there some features in the KML data that Google Earth can handle, but Google Maps can't?

Many thanks for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document id="Created by GrADS-2.1.a3">
<Style id="56">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffc83c48</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffc83c48</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="49">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffd26414</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffd26414</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="47">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>fff08228</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>fff08228</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="45">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>fff5a550</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>fff5a550</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="43">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>fffad296</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>fffad296</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="41">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffffffe1</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffffffe1</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="1">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffffffff</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffffffff</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="32">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffbeffc8</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffbeffc8</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="33">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffaafab4</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffaafab4</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="34">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff8cf596</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff8cf596</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="35">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff73f578</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff73f578</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="37">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff3cd237</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff3cd237</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="21">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffaafaff</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffaafaff</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="22">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff78e8ff</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff78e8ff</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="23">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff3cc0ff</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff3cc0ff</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="24">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff00a0ff</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff00a0ff</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="25">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff0060ff</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff0060ff</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="26">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff0032ff</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff0032ff</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="27">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff0014e1</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff0014e1</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="28">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff0000c0</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff0000c0</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="29">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ff0000a5</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ff0000a5</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="55">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffdc6070</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffdc6070</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="56">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffc83c48</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffc83c48</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Style id="57">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>ffb4283c</color>
    <width>0</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>ffb4283c</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
  <styleUrl>#33</styleUrl>
  <name>3 to 5</name>
  <Polygon>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
          6.30084,60.0071,0 6.32486,60.0179,0 6.35121,60.0071,0 6.32486,59.9889,0 6.30084,60.0071,0 
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <styleUrl>#33</styleUrl>
  <name>3 to 5</name>
  <Polygon>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
          6.93315,60.0612,0 6.91946,60.095,0 6.90916,60.1152,0 6.88215,60.1693,0 6.91946,60.1737,0 6.97351,60.1738,0 
          6.98845,60.1693,0 7.02756,60.1586,0 7.07997,60.1152,0 7.07345,60.0612,0 7.02756,60.0377,0 6.97351,60.0314,0 
          6.93315,60.0612,0 
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <styleUrl>#33</styleUrl>
  <name>3 to 5</name>
  <Polygon>
    <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
      <LinearRing>
        <coordinates>
          7.27598,60.6017,0 7.29783,60.6188,0 7.31795,60.6017,0 7.29783,60.5971,0 7.27598,60.6017,0 
        </coordinates>
      </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>
</Placemark>
and so on...
```

Comment: what if you set tesselate to 0, any difference?

Comment: To know more about KML, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut). And for more insight you can also check the [differences between Google Earth and Google Maps](http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2014/07/differences-google-earth-google-maps.html).

Comment: Thanks both, setting tesselate equal to zero didn't change the image unfortunately and the lines were still present